# Publishing InfoPath form to SharePoint

Tags: infopath, publishing

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a form in Infopath that allows users to view/insert/edit data that resides in a SQL table, and publish that InfoPath form to a SharePoint site. I understand that normally you cannot have users submit form data on a browser-enabled form to a SQL database. I guess the question is, does your form need to be browser-enabled in order for it to be used in Sharepoint?

Comment: what versions of SharePoint & InfoPath are you using?

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath form doesn't have to be browser enabled but in that case users must have InfoPath client to work with it.

External list can work for your case too.